# How to prove the Inequality $\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{a}<\sqrt[n]{b-a}$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

Let $0<a<b$ using Lagrange mean value theorem I want to prove the following inequality

> $\sqrt[n]{b}-\sqrt[n]{a}<\sqrt[n]{b-a}$

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $f(x) = \sqrt[n]{x-a}$. Since $b>a$, the interval $(a+a,b+a)$ is not empty and apply the Lagrange there. That is, we can find $\xi \in (2a, b+a)$ so that

$$ f(b+a) - f(2a) = f'(\xi) (b-a) $$

which reduces to

$$ \sqrt[n]{b} - \sqrt[n]{a} = \frac{1}{n} (\xi - a)^{1/n-1} (b-a) \leq \frac{1}{n}(b-a)^{1/n-1}(b-a) < \sqrt[n]{b-a} $$

Since $\xi \leq b$

Comment: But as the exponent $1/n - 1 < 0$, the function $x\longmapsto x^{1/n-1}$ is decreasing and  $\xi\le b\implies (\xi - a)^{1/n-1}\ge (b-a)^{1/n-1}$.

Comment: And your intermediate inequality $\sqrt[n]{b} - \sqrt[n]{a}\le \frac{1}{n} (b - a)^{1/n-1} (b-a)$ is false for $n =2$, $a = 1$, $b = 9$.